# If $X$ is an orthogonal matrix, why does $X^TX = I$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, inner-products

It's not immediately clear to me why this is true. My notes say that putting $n$ orthonormal vectors $ v_1, ..., v_n$ in the columns of $X$ gives $X^TX = I$, and it follows from this that the rows of $X$ are orthonormal.

Can you explain this better to me? I tried the $2\times 2$ case, but it isn't clear to me why this is true.

Comment: The condition $X^TX=I$ is sometimes, and even often, the definition of an orthognonal matrix. You should precise your definition in the question. Do I understand that it is: the rows are orthonormal?

Comment: I don't see why it's true. Let's say that (a, b) and (c, d) are orthonormal vectors in X. Then a^2 + b^2 = 1, c^2 + d^2 = 1, and ac + bd = 0. Now when you multiply X by its transpose you get a^2 + c^2 = 1, b^2 + d^2 = 1, and ab + cd = 0 I don't see why that's true.

Comment: Just work out the problem on a $2\times 2$ matrix and you will see it.

Comment: @julien Since the answer is asked the way it is, I take it his definition is: an orthogonal matrix is a square matrix whose column vectors constitute an orthonormal set of vectors (or orthonormal basis).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Note the OP's conclusion is about rows, not columns.

Comment: @julien : That works as a definition only if the number of rows equals the number of columns.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Sure. The only thing that I took for granted in the OP's question is that $X$ is a square real matrix. But apparently we will never know what the OP's definition was...

Comment: X is a square matrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more visual, though not rigorous approach.

Let $X=[v_1|\cdots|v_n\textbf{]}$ be a a orthogonal matrix, where $v_i,\ldots ,v_n$ are $n$-dimensional column vectors.

Then $X^TX=\begin{bmatrix}\underline{v_1}\\\vdots\\\overline{v_n}\end{bmatrix}[v_1|\cdots|v_n\textbf{]}=\begin{bmatrix}v_1\cdot v_1 & v_1\cdot v_2 &\cdots &v_1 \cdot v_n\\
v_2\cdot v_1 &v_2\cdot v_2 &\cdots &v_2\cdot v_n\\
\vdots &\vdots &\ddots &\vdots\\
\vdots &\vdots &\ddots &\vdots\\
v_n\cdot v_1& v_n\cdot v_2 &\cdots &v_n\cdot v_n\end{bmatrix}=I_n$

Comment: This helped me visualize it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Multiplying $\,X^tX\,$ , for a square matrix $\,X\,$, is the same as doing the inner product of the columns of $\,X^t\,$ = the rows of $\,X^t\,$ ,  when we look at them as $\,n$-th vectors...

$$X=(a_{ij})\implies X^t=(b_{ij})\;,\;\;b_{ij}=a_{ji}\;,\;\;1\le i,j\le n\implies$$

$$X^tX=\left(\sum_{k=1}^nb_{ik}a_{kj}\right)=\left(\sum_{k=1}^na_{ki}a_{kj}\right)=\delta_{ij}$$

Comment: Given $X^TX$, it should be "columns" and not "rows". I think.

Comment: Well, since I only wrote "its rows" we could guess whether I meant $\,X\,$ or $\,X^t\,$ ...:) But you're right: the columns of $\,X\,$ = rows of $\,X\,$ . Thanks

Comment: Of course, you're right @GitGud . The last one must be $\,X^t\,$, thanks.

Comment: There is still a typo. It should be "columns of $X$". Or vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

Who is the $(i,j)$ element of the product $A \cdot B$ ? Answer: it is the canonical scalar product beetween i-th row of A and j-th column of B. That should answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the matrix $Y = X^TX$. For every $i,j$ between $1$ and $n$, the $(i,j)$-th entry $y_{ij}$ of $Y$ is simply the dot product (scalar product) of the $i$-th column and the $j$-th column of $X$. (The $i$-th *row* of $X^T$ is the $i$-th *column* of $X$.) Evaluate this when $i\ne j$, and when $i=j$.