# How to show an arbitrary set is orthonormal?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonality

I have to show that the rows and columns of a unitary matrix are orthonormal sets.  I have not been provided with a specific matrix, just 'a unitary matrix.'  I understand how to show that given vectors are orthonormal, and I know that if the rows of a unitary matrix are orthonormal, then the columns are as well, but I can't think of how to prove this with an arbitrary matrix.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How are the the entries of a product of two matrices related to the rows and columns of the two matrices?

Comment: [The real case of this result](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/361520/if-x-is-an-orthogonal-matrix-why-does-xtx-i/361537#361537).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two (complex) vectors are orthogonal iff $$\sum_i a_i^*b_i = 0$$
A matrix $U$ is unitary iff $U^\dagger U = I$.

A set of vectors is orthonormal if each vector in the set has norm of $1$, that is, 
$\sum a_i^*a_i = 1$, and for all pairs of two distinct vectors in the set, 
$\sum_i a_i^*b_i = 0$.

Suppose, now,  that $U$ is unitary, and let $\vec{a}$ be the $k$-th column of $U$, and 
let $\vec{b}$ be the $j$-th column of $U$, with $k\neq j$. Then by the rules of matrix multiplication
$$\sum_i a_i^*b_i =   (U^\dagger U)_{kj} = I_{kj} == 0 $$ so $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ are orthogonal.

Now let $\vec{b}$ be the $k$-th column of $U$ so that the two columns are the same column.  Then 
$$\sum_i a_i^*a_i =   (U^\dagger U)_{kk} = I_{kk} == 1 $$ so $\vec{a}$ is of norm $1$, that is to say, it is normal.

Thus the set of vectors is orthonormal.

Comment: Up voted with a warning. I could do without the double equal signs $\ddot \smile$

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful!  It's been a few years since I took linear algebra, this was a great refresher.